# bootstrap modal dismiss stopping from from submitting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a contact form in a Bootstrap modal, and I want that when the form submits, the modal hides, with the "fade" animation. However, the form does not submit when I add a `data-dismiss="modal"` to the "submit" button. 
HTML :

```
<div class="modal fade cont">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form action="form.php" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Contact</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Name:
                        <input type="text" autofocus name="name" id="name" class="form-control" id="fd">
                    </p>
                    <p>Email:
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" />
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." name="copy">
                          </span>
                          <input type="text" readonly disabled class="form-control" aria-label="" value="Check here for a copy of your message." style="border:1px solid #ccc !important;cursor:default !important;" />
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <p>Message:
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="msg" name="msg" style="height:175px;"></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    <input type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the form submit when the "fade" hide goes.
**[Page](http://tricksfortheweb.net46.net)** Click on contact link in nav bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(this).parents(".modal").fadeOut(300, function() {
    your callback function here ... });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just used `$(".cont").modal('hide');` but that works too. :)